# Want a query to find the missed numbers in DB

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization

I have a table `part` with a few demo data as below in Oracle DB:

```
ID    NUMBER     DESCRIPTION
1     T00001     test
2     T00002     test
3     T00003     test
4     T00004     test
5     T00008     test
6     SG0001     test
7     SG0002     test
8     SG0003     test
9     SG0004     test
10    SG0006     test
```

The column `NUMBER` defines different category part with different predefined prefix and auto-incremental number suffix.  Now in DB there have been some numbers missed so the continuity is broken. I want a SQL query or PL-SQL function with perfect performance to list the missed numbers:

e.g: for the above demo data. the following data should be returned:

```
 Category1 start with T: T00005,T00006,T00007 
 Category1 start with SG: SG0005
```

Anybody have ideas?

Comment: Is the list of alpha prefixes limited to just the 2 values shown, or could there be others?  Also, are you sure it matters when there are gaps?  Can you afford to treat `T0` as a 2-character prefix, or could the `T` series get to `T10000`?  Would it matter if the gaps in the `T0` series and the `T1` series were listed separately?

Comment: @JammyC.c - If you like answers, you should vote them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SG:

```
WITH t AS ( 
    SELECT 
        0 as start_n, 
        p.a as end_n 
    FROM (
        SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR("NUMBER", 3))) a FROM Part p2 
        WHERE "NUMBER" LIKE 'SG%') p
)
SELECT 
    'SG' || LPAD(r.cur_num, 4, '0') AS missing_expr
FROM 
    (SELECT t.start_n + level - 1 AS cur_num FROM t CONNECT BY t.start_n + level - 1 <= t.end_n) r
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM part p WHERE p."NUMBER" = 'SG' || LPAD(r.cur_num, 4, '0')
    )
ORDER BY missing_expr ASC;
```

For T:

```
WITH t AS ( 
    SELECT 
        0 as start_n, 
        p.a as end_n 
    FROM (
        SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR("NUMBER", 2))) a FROM Part p2 
        WHERE "NUMBER" LIKE 'T%') p
)
SELECT
    'T' || LPAD(r.cur_num, 5, '0') AS missing_expr
FROM 
    (SELECT t.start_n + level - 1 AS cur_num FROM t CONNECT BY t.start_n + level - 1 <= t.end_n) r
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM part p WHERE p.number = 'T' || LPAD(r.cur_num, 5, '0')
    )
ORDER BY missing_expr ASC
```

Comment: Many Thanks, I copied your query to Oracle SQL developer but got a compile error. what "WITH t AS" WITH t AS?

Comment: weird... I'm going to try on a sqlfiddle

Comment: Thanks, what "WITH t AS" mean? is it a part of this query?

Comment: @Sebas:Hardcoding  the prefix is not a good way of doing ,because its just the demo data jammy specified .

Comment: @JammyC.c:does your table contains that starts with SG and T ?

Comment: my table has more than 1 million rows, will this query may has any potential risk or performance issue?

Comment: hm, risk no, but performances maybe. Connect by clause usually has poor performances. Let me check...

Comment: Yeah, it's going to be slow :D Maybe a pl/sql block would be better, I don't really know. It also depends of your structure

Comment: @Sebas SQL Fiddle had some issues a moment ago, but it's back up and running now: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73a27/9

Comment: Oh, thanks Jake :-) How cool to "meet" the dev of SqlFiddle :-)

Comment: No prob.  Nice to meet you too! In case you're curious - here's the background on the problem I had - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/railo/2yr8mtoXrlQ - fortunately I think I discovered the root cause and have now coded around it - https://github.com/jakefeasel/sqlfiddle/commit/0c2a12296fc861c2cf098a7fb303c70f8e64151d - thanks for the heads-up that something wasn't working.

Comment: i canceled my whine though... apologize!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of options. This is called the "Islands and Gaps" problem. Try looking at the following resources (Most will work in Oracle as well as SQL server. Some may require tweaking):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175780(v=sql.80).aspx

or

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced+Querying/anefficientsetbasedsolutionforislandsandgaps/1619/

Comment: Thanks, do you have any links or materials provided a good solutions on Oracle?

Comment: Yes - those links. The syntax may change slightly, but the solutions are the same. If you need the best possible Oracle optimized solution, ("perfect performance") you may want to ask a co-worker at Oracle who deals with designing the database engines.

Answer (score 0):

For the T use:

```
 select 'T' || substr('0000' || to_char(r.rn),length(to_char(r.rn)-1))
    from (select rownum rn from part 
        where rownum <= (select max(to_number(substr(p.number,2))) from part p 
                         where p.number like 'T%'
                        )
       ) r
     where 
      'T' || substr('0000' || to_char(r.rn),length(to_char(r.rn)-1)) 
      not in (select p.number from part p where p.number like 'T%');
```

For SG use:

```
select 'SG' || substr('000' || to_char(r.rn),length(to_char(r.rn)-1))
    from (select rownum rn from part 
      where rownum <= (select max(to_number(substr(p.number,3))) from part p 
                       where p.number like 'SG%'
                      )
     ) r
where 
  'SG' || substr('000' || to_char(r.rn),length(to_char(r.rn)-1)) 
  not in (select p.number from part p where p.number like 'SG%');
```

A couple of things to note:

1)  I'm using the table PART to get a rownum value.  Any table can be used if it has enough rows. If you use this approach make sure that you are using a table large enough to pull in the desired range of values.  USER_OBJECTS could work as well.  PART may not have enough values to work with.

2)  It seems that NUMBER as a column name would cause you problems.  It is a reserved word in Oracle.  In my testing I used a different column name.